# Protractor not able to count links in a list (li)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, element

This is my first message, basically because is the first time that I have not been able to find the answer to my question.

I am trying to count the number of li elements in a dropdown. Each `<li> has a`` link. Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div ko-dropdown="ko-dropdown" ng-keyup="onKeyup($event)" ng-keydown="onKeydown($event)" class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" ta-items="languages" ta-value="language" ta-onselect="select(lang)">
  <div ng-click="toggle()" ng-class="{'is-open': open}" class="dropdown__toggle  dropdown__toggle--top">English</div>
  <ul ko-drop-menu="ko-drop-menu" ng-mouseleave="onMouseLeave($event)" class="dropdown__menu">
    <!-- ngRepeat: item in items track by $index -->
    <li ko-drop-item="ko-drop-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-mouseenter="onMouseEnter($event, item)" ng-click="select($event, item)" ng-class="{'is-active': item.selected}" class="dropdown__item ng-scope is-active"><a class="dropdown__link ng-binding ng-scope" href="" ng-bind="::item[label]" data-value="en">English</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: item in items track by $index -->
    <li ko-drop-item="ko-drop-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-mouseenter="onMouseEnter($event, item)" ng-click="select($event, item)" ng-class="{'is-active': item.selected}" class="dropdown__item ng-scope"><a class="dropdown__link ng-binding ng-scope" href="" ng-bind="::item[label]" data-value="fi">Suomi</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: item in items track by $index -->
    <li ko-drop-item="ko-drop-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-mouseenter="onMouseEnter($event, item)" ng-click="select($event, item)" ng-class="{'is-active': item.selected}" class="dropdown__item ng-scope"><a class="dropdown__link ng-binding ng-scope" href="" ng-bind="::item[label]" data-value="sv">Svenska</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: item in items track by $index -->
    <li ko-drop-item="ko-drop-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-mouseenter="onMouseEnter($event, item)" ng-click="select($event, item)" ng-class="{'is-active': item.selected}" class="dropdown__item ng-scope"><a class="dropdown__link ng-binding ng-scope" href="" ng-bind="::item[label]" data-value="no">Norsk</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: item in items track by $index -->
    <li ko-drop-item="ko-drop-item" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-mouseenter="onMouseEnter($event, item)" ng-click="select($event, item)" ng-class="{'is-active': item.selected}" class="dropdown__item ng-scope"><a class="dropdown__link ng-binding ng-scope" href="" ng-bind="::item[label]" data-value="de">Deutsch</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: item in items track by $index -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

The correct number of elements that protractor should return is 5  but when looking for the number of elements I am getting always 10.

I am using this piece of code to call but as said before I always get 10 even combining with dropdown__link, etc:

```
`elements.all(by.css('.dropdown__menu .dropdown__item')).count()`
```

Comment: Please take a moment to [add some formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to your question, in the current form it is really hard to read

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements on a page having `dropdown__menu` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you selector more specific:

```
div[ta-items=languages] ul.dropdown__menu > li.dropdown__item
```

Or, by chaining `element` and `element.all` and `by.repeater`:

```
var languageMenu = element(by.css("div[ta-items=languages]"));
var languages = languageMenu.all(by.repeater("item in items"));

expect(languages.count()).toEqual(5);
```

Comment: element(by.css("div[ta-items=languages]")).all(by.repeater("item in items")).count()

Comment: @JamesBe okay, that was a logical move.

Comment: Thanks alecxe. I meant to say that `element(by.css("div[ta-items=languages]")).all(by.repeater("item in items")).count()` worked and thanks! :)

Comment: Just before closing and if you are kind enough to answer this ;)
If I want to access each element inside `var languages` by position?
I have tried `.get(pos)` and nothing. thanks!!

Comment: @JamesBe it should be e.g. `languages.get(2)`, or `languages.first()` or `languages.last()`. What problems do you have using it?

Comment: Sorted! 
I was just assuming that the get(0) was giving me the element with the text, so using `languagues.get(0).getText()` would be correct.
But no, it was giving me the first `<li>` element so now doing this works:
`var first = languages.get(0).element(by.css('.dropdown__link')).getText();
        expect(first).toEqual('ENGLISH');`

SOLVED! THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

```
arr=browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName("a"));

for(var x = 0; x < arr.count; x++) 
{
    console.log('vishnu');
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```